# AngularJS and Razor Kendo Events

Tags: angularjs, razor, kendo-ui, grid, event-binding

We have a project built with cshtml template and AngularJS. We're currently revisiting its implementation and we're trying to introduce Razor templates and AngularJS combined. We're trying to declare Kendo UI controls inside the page using Razor. Example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(....))
```

This line of code is wrapped with a AngularJS Controller, example:

```
<div ng-controller="UserController as vm">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(....))
</div>
```

So far we're successful defining the controls and binding the data. However we're not successful finding ways how to bind events that resides inside the AngularJS controller. Events like DataBound, Change, etc.

Can anyone please advise if this is even possible and provide examples? I reached out to Telerik Support and they're suggesting that its not advisable to combine Razor and AngularJS for it has limitations. This is all trial and error for us and we're searching for suggestions if someone has tried this before.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't Kendo have a full set of controls specifically for use with Angular? The problem with the regular Kendo (MVC) controls is that they use jQuery. Angular and jQuery do not play well together because they are both DOM manipulation frameworks. That's likely why Telerik advised against using this set of controls with Angular.

Comment: Yes we know that they have Angular and we're already using it. We're just exploring the possibility of combining the two.